# Possible to restore LUKS header from partition that uses the exact same password and keyfile?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, disk-encryption, file-encryption, luks

I was in Windows 10 and it told me I needed to Initialize Disk so I clicked it and now my LUKS header has been overwritten. I created my encrypted partitions in Linux with `cryptsetup` command. **However,** I have another drive that uses the same password and keyfile as the one with the overwritten partition header, ... and I was wondering if it would be possible to backup the good partition header and use it for the one that has been overwritten since both LUKS encrypted partitions were created the same time, and with the exact same password/keyfile?

If anyone has experience in my position, I would be immensely grateful if you could point me in the right direction, or just tell me if am I screwed.

Thanks so much...

Comment: The LUKS header contains the encrypted master key. If you wiped the whole thing out then you won't be able to decrypt the volume even with the keyfiles/passwords.

Comment: If the second partition/header is cloned from the first then you will be able to use it, but if you used two separate `cryptsetup format` commands then they'll have different master keys.

Comment: @user Please don't post answers as comments.

Comment: @MechMK1 dw I'll convert it to an answer if the information is correct.

Comment: So am I screwed? All I did was click 'Initialize Disk' in windows. That was literally ALL I DID. Please don't tell me I'm screwed :/

Comment: @AnonUser Did you use cryptsetup on the entire device, or did you create partitions?

Comment: @user I did the entire device to use it as a backup space drive for backup files. Is there anything that can help me?

Comment: @AnonUser You'll need to research Windows' disk initialization to see how much it actually overwrites, and then check the cryptsetup format command to see what all is written to the disk. If you're lucky it will have only overwritten parts that you can reconstruct, but more likely it will have overwritten parts of the key.